# RPATH is not used for java JNI library

Tags: java, java-native-interface, rpath

It is a CentOS 7.5 aarch64 box. I installed gcc 6.1 in my directory /opt/build, and used the new version to build a jni library, with -Wl,-rpath=/opt/build/lib.
So the jni library was bound to /opt/build/lib/libstdc++.so.6. I have doubled checked that with ldd and chrpath.
Then I used java -jar app.jar to try it.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/app/lib/libmylib.so.3.14.0: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /opt/app/lib/libmylib.so.3.14.0)

It is clear that /opt/app/lib/libmylib.so.3.14.0 will try to link to /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 even if the RPATH is set to /opt/build/lib.

Don't know why...

Comment: Assuming you're running on Linux, did you try running your JVM under `strace` and tracing the system calls made when your native library is loaded?

Comment: I have straced it, the jvm tried to load libstdc++.so.6 from JRE_HOME/lib/aarch64/libstdc++.so.6, then /lib/libstdc++.so.6, totally ignored RPATH.

Comment: Did you manage to get around this? I'm having the exact same issue